# Jenkins Pipeline - Restrict where this project can be run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins pipeline (Jenkins version - v2.73.2 ,Jenkins pipeline - 2.5) and wanted to force my job to use only two windows slave machines 'Jenkins-s1' or 'Jenkins-s2' which ever is available. To do this I know in legacy Jenkins we have option "Restrict where this project can be run" in the configure page. 
Upon googling, with Jenkins pipeline 2, we can mention in the pipeline script as

```html
node('Jenkins-s1||Jenkins-s2') {
    
    stage ('Checkout') {
 ............ }
 
 stage ('Build'){
 ............ }
 
 stage ('Deploy') {
 ............ }
 }
```

Which seems to be hard-code in the code and have to mention same in every child job. Therefore, i am looking for suggestions if there are any plugins available in Jenkins pipeline 2 which gives me option "Restrict where this project can be run" in the configure page or is there any other way i can handle this scenario.

Please share your inputs.

Comment: I don't really see what's wrong with putting it there. It's maybe a bit cleaner when you label those 2 nodes and run it on the agent with label "xxx". If you really want it to make dynamically you can use parameterized pipelines and provide this value as parameter. Here you see an example of parameterized jenkins pipelines: https://lvthillo.com/reusable-jenkins-pipeline-for-maven-jobs/